# How does JUnit know which class to be tested?

Tags: java, junit

I have two classes `Calculator1` and `Calculator2` which are in the package called `com.zzy.junit.user` under the src folder. I use myeclipse to create two test classes to test them respectively. When I execute the one test class among them, how does Junit4 know which class is tested?

#### Class 1

```
package com.zzy.junit.user;

public class Calculator1 {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Calculator1(int a,int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int add()
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

#### Class 2

```
package com.zzy.junit.user;

public class Calculator2{

    public int divide(int a,int b)
    {
        return a/b;
    }
}
```

And two test classes as follows:
They are both in the src folder called test

#### Test Class 1

```
package com.zzy.junit.user;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;  

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCalculator1 {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Calculator1 s = new Calculator1(3,6);
        int z = s.add();
        assertThat(z,is(9));
    }

}
```

#### Test Class 2

```
package com.zzy.junit.user;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCalculator2 {

    @Test
    public void testDivide() {
        TestCalculator2 t = new TestCalculator2();
        int z = t.divide(4, 2);
        assertThat(z,is(2));
    }

}
```

I want to know if I execute the test class called `TestCalculator2`, how does Junit4 know I do want to test `Calculator1` class. Is it related to the name of the test class?

Comment: Usually the test code specifies what class it's testing.  We might be able to explain in a bit more detail if you post your test class code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!And I have posted the two test classes!

Comment: @zzy7186 Your code makes no sense at all. Why do you have calculator-related classes mixed in with your teacher/student classes? Have you posted the right code?

Comment: @Duncan Jones sorry I made a mistake,I have fixed the code now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit is a framework for executing tests that can pass or fail. The fact that a single test typically focusses on a single class is a convention observed by most Java programmers. JUnit4 doesn't *know* which classes are being tested, it merely executes all methods annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: +1:  The best answer, though I happily added my two cents based on the posted test code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually because its name ends on "Test"or because it has the @Test annotation.

Comment: Thank you for you rely! According to you,if I change the name of the test class,Junit4 should not know which class I want to test.But when I change TestCaculator2 to ExecuteCaculator2,and the code is still work.can you explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your (previous) posted test code, the `testAdd` method in `TestCaculator1` is testing an `add` method in `Student` and the `testDivide` method in `TestCaculator1` is testing a `divide` method in `Teacher`.

With your last edit, the test class names now more closely align to the names of the tested classes.

As noted in another answer, there's no real requirement that a test class be dedicated to testing a specific class, though people tend to establish a one-for-one relation by convention.

The real connection is at the method level and is entirely determined by what class the test methods actually exercise.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my English grammatical mistakes and the code style.I will try my best to study English,so I can reduce mistake of English.Through you reply,I have better understanding of the `junit4`.Thanks a lot!